# Understanding derivation in Calculus of Variations book

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations

I'm reading about Calculus of Variations and about the general variation of a functional. I bumped into few obstacles in my book I can't get over with.

I have scanned the pages where I have my confusion. I have highlighted my problem areas in different colors :

**1. (GREEN)** I don't understand why

$$\int_{x_1}^{x_1+\delta x_1}F(x,y+h,y'+h')\;dx-\int_{x_0}^{x_0+\delta x_0}F(x,y+h,y'+h')\;dx$$

equals $$F(x,y,y')|_{x=x_1}\delta x_1 -F(x,y,y')|_{x=x_0}\delta x_0$$

details?

**2. (RED)** What does this **~** notation actually mean? I'm confused with this...example?

**3. (BLUE)** To me this is not clear...details?

**4.** What is meant by the sentence (in page 55): "by a quantity of order higher than 1 relative to $\rho(y,y+h)$"?

In case you don't see the image clearly enough just right-click --> show in another tab, etc. Sorry for posting an image but this would have been quite a task to write in LaTex.

[image]

Please let me know if my questions are unclear. Thank you!

Comment: See [Taylor's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem) : **Statement of the theorem** : the terms of "order higher than 1" are those with the second (or higher) derivative.

Comment: Thank you @MauroALLEGRANZA the statement "relative to $\rho(y,y+h)$ confuses me here, because I don't see the term $\rho(y,y+h)$ used anywhere in the equations...

Comment: The function $\rho$ is the "distance" between the two curves; it takes the role of the "increment" $(x-a)$ in the formula of Taylor's expansion.

Comment: Thank you @MauroALLEGRANZA that helped :) Appreciate your help.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Hi, it seems I'm not getting an answer for my question here :) Do you think I could post this question in math overflow?